# Xcode 4.5 determine if uiwebview can scroll up

Tags: uiwebview, uiscrollview, uikit

Do you guys have any ideas how to call a method every time a certain uiwebview is all the way up on the page ie. so that it can't scroll up? This function would be great to be able to refresh a page in a smart way.

/Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

In the .h, your code should look something like:

`@interface iSafeViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>`

Then in the .m

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //The webview is is scrolling
    float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (scrollOffset <= 1)
    {
        // then we are at the top

    }
    else if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight >= scrollContentSizeHeight - 1)
    {
        // then we are at the end

    }
    else
    {
        //We are somewhere in the middle
    }
}
```

You will need to set your webView's scrollView delegate though like this:

`[webView.scrollView setDelegate:self];`

If that doesn't work let me know.

Comment: It works great, thank you! One thing though, I get this issue: Sending 'FirstViewController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<UIScrollViewDelegate>' . Do you know how I get rid of that? It's at the "[webView.scrollView setDelegate:self];" in the .m file.

Comment: Oh yeah, in your header, add UIScrollViewDelegate. I'll edit my asnwer for clarity.

Comment: Thank you again! This works really well on the iPad but not on the iPhone, do you understand why? I have the same header and implementation file linked to both iPhone and iPad, but two different uiwebviews.

Comment: So you have a different Web view for iPhone. Why not just use the same one? However, it works fine for me on iPhone.

Comment: Yes, because I want a slightly different version of the webpage on the iPhone. It didn't work because i forgot to set the delegate for the other webview ^^

Comment: Yes exactly the result I was searching for. Thank you, I would vote up your answer but it requires 15 points. I have accepted it though.

Comment: Though FYI, I believe you have 15 rep now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`UIWebView` has a `scrollView` property. This is `UIScrollView` set what ever object you want to the delegate:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id<UIScrollViewDelegate> delegate
```

Now you will get all the delegate callbacks:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
- (void)scrollViewDidScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```